# Python: how to write data to an already open excel file (no path specified)?

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, xlsx

I'm trying to write data to an excel file that is already open and saved with a specific filename. I need to do this without specifying a file path.

What I have below is not writing anything to the spreadsheet.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({data1, data2, data3})
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("*open_excel_filename*.xlsx")
df.to_excel(writer,"Sheet1",startrow=1,startcol=1)
```

Comment: if the excel file is opened by anyone other than yourself there is no way to write to it, unless your using Excel Online/Sharepoint. Even then you'll need to use the o365 api or something like XLwings, - secondly _if_ you can't specify the path how will the program know where the excel fiel is?

Comment: The excel file is open by only myself. That's my question, is how do I write to an open excel file based only on filename, instead of file path? Seems like there should be a "find_open_excel_doc_by_filename" command or something